# Intersection of a projective curve and a hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, projective-space, plane-curves

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a projective curve on $\mathbb{P}^2$ over a field $k$ defined by $\Phi(x,y,z)$ such that it is homogenization of an affine curve $\Phi(x,y)$. When we look at the intersection of $\mathcal{C}$ and the hyperplane defined by $\{ x=0 \}$, does it define an affine curve or a projective curve?
To be more clear, the intersection of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\{ x=0\}$ will be defined by $\Phi(0,y,z)$ and it is homogenous. Since it has only 2 indeterminates, does it define a projective curve on $\mathbb{P}^2$? Or does it defines an affine curve?

Comment: Neither, usually - you get a finite set of points, unless that curve is already $V(x)$.

Comment: does it depend on the field? If the field is a finite field, is it still neither? for example, we have an affine curve $\mathcal{C}$ defined by $\Phi(x,y)= ax^i +by^j +cy^k$ with $i >j >k$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Take homogenization of this curve by $\Phi(x,y,z)= ax^i +by^j z^{i-j} +cy^k z^{i-k} $, now we have a projective curve. Taking the intersection with hyperplane $\{ x= 0 \}$, we will have $\Phi(0,y,z)= by^j z^{i-j} +cy^k z^{i-k} $, does it defines a projective curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: Because, my main aim is obtaining points of the form $[0:y:z]$ on the projective curve $\Phi(x,y,z)$ looking $\Phi(0,y,z)$, I am wondering that it defines a curve or not if it is like the example above.

Comment: You're taking the intersection of a $\Bbb P^1$ and a closed set in $\Bbb P^2$. This means it's a closed set of $\Bbb P^1$. These are finite sets of points or the whole thing. This does not depend on the underlying field.